# Unable to connect VNC to ESX during packer build

Tags: vnc, packer, esx

I've been attempting to use the `vmware-iso` builder in packer to generate a base Centos 7 image that I can build other images off (using `vmware-vmx`). Unfortunately, the build keeps failing when attempting to find an open VNC port to connect to.

I've followed the various guides and existing issues, so I'm on the latest version of packer (0.12.2) and I've got ports 5900-6000 open on the firewall. Every now and then, the build manages to find a port and completes just fine, but nothing I've attempted has been able to get this consistently happening.

It looks as though the VNC check happens before the VMX config is written, so specifying values in the `vmx_data` section doesn't have any effect.

I've run the build on Windows 10, inside the packer docker container, and on a Centos 7 vm with no difference in the result.

Here's the config I'm using for the build:

```
{
  "description": "A bare centos server.",
  "min_packer_version": "0.10.0",
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "vmware-iso",
      "guest_os_type": "centos-64",
      "headless": false,
      "remote_type": "esx5",
      "remote_host": "{{ user `vmware_host` }}",
      "remote_username": "{{ user `vmware_user` }}",
      "remote_password": "{{ user `vmware_pass` }}",
      "remote_datastore": "{{ user `vmware_data` }}",
      "vmx_data": {
        "ethernet0.networkName": "{{ user `vmware_conn` }}",
        "ethernet0.present": "TRUE",
        "ethernet0.startConnected": "TRUE",
        "ethernet0.virtualDev": "e1000",
        "ethernet0.addressType": "generated",
        "ethernet0.wakeOnPcktRcv": "FALSE",
        "ethernet0.uptCompatibility": "TRUE"
      },
      "vmx_data_post": {
        "ethernet0.virtualDev": "vmxnet3"
      },
      "disk_size": 16384,
      "floppy_files": [
        "{{ pwd }}/files/centos-kickstart.cfg"
      ],
      "iso_url": "file:///{{ pwd }}/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso",
      "iso_checksum": "27bd866242ee058b7a5754e83d8ee8403e216b93d130d800852a96f41c34d86a",
      "iso_checksum_type": "sha256",
      "boot_wait": "5s",
      "boot_command": [
        "<tab> text ks=hd:fd0:/centos-kickstart.cfg<enter><wait>"
      ],
      "ssh_wait_timeout": "10m",
      "ssh_username": "root",
      "ssh_password": "packer",
      "shutdown_command": "shutdown -hP now",
      "shutdown_timeout": "3m"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here are the (tastefully truncated) logs of the build process:

```
> docker run -it -e PACKER_LOG=1 -v $(pwd):/opt/ -w /opt/ hashicorp/packer:light build -var-file=env.json packer.json 
2017/02/02 02:06:40 [INFO] Packer version: 0.12.2
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Packer Target OS/Arch: linux amd64
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Built with Go Version: go1.7.4
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Detected home directory from env var: /root
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for azure-arm
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for file
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for null
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for openstack
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for parallels-pvm
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for qemu
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for vmware-vmx
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for amazon-chroot
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for amazon-ebs
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for digitalocean
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for oneandone
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for profitbricks
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for triton
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for virtualbox-ovf
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for amazon-ebsvolume
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for amazon-instance
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for cloudstack
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for googlecompute
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for hyperv-iso
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for vmware-iso
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for docker
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for parallels-iso
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for virtualbox-iso
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for powershell
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for salt-masterless
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for ansible-local
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for chef-solo
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for converge
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for shell
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for windows-restart
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for ansible
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for puppet-server
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for windows-shell
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for chef-client
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for file
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for puppet-masterless
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for shell-local
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for checksum
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for docker-tag
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for googlecompute-export
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for vagrant
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for atlas
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for compress
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for docker-import
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for docker-push
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for artifice
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for manifest
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for shell-local
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for vsphere
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for amazon-import
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for docker-save
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Using internal plugin for vagrant-cloud
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Detected home directory from env var: /root
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Attempting to open config file: /root/.packerconfig
2017/02/02 02:06:40 [WARN] Config file doesn't exist: /root/.packerconfig
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Packer config: &{DisableCheckpoint:false DisableCheckpointSignature:false PluginMinPort:10000 PluginMaxPort:25000 Builders:map[azure-arm:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-azure-arm amazon-chroot:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-amazon-chroot triton:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-triton cloudstack:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-cloudstack googlecompute:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-googlecompute file:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-file null:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-null openstack:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-openstack parallels-pvm:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-parallels-pvm vmware-vmx:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-vmware-vmx amazon-ebsvolume:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-amazon-ebsvolume vmware-iso:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-vmware-iso virtualbox-iso:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-virtualbox-iso qemu:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-qemu digitalocean:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-digitalocean profitbricks:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-profitbricks amazon-instance:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-amazon-instance parallels-iso:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-parallels-iso amazon-ebs:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-amazon-ebs oneandone:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-oneandone virtualbox-ovf:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-virtualbox-ovf hyperv-iso:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-hyperv-iso docker:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-builder-docker] PostProcessors:map[vagrant-cloud:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-post-processor-vagrant-cloud googlecompute-export:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-post-processor-googlecompute-export docker-save:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-post-processor-docker-save manifest:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-post-processor-manifest docker-push:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-post-processor-docker-push artifice:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-post-processor-artifice atlas:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-post-processor-atlas compress:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-post-processor-compress docker-import:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-post-processor-docker-import shell-local:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-post-processor-shell-local checksum:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-post-processor-checksum vagrant:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-post-processor-vagrant amazon-import:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-post-processor-amazon-import docker-tag:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-post-processor-docker-tag vsphere:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-post-processor-vsphere] Provisioners:map[powershell:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-provisioner-powershell chef-solo:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-provisioner-chef-solo windows-restart:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-provisioner-windows-restart shell-local:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-provisioner-shell-local salt-masterless:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-provisioner-salt-masterless ansible-local:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-provisioner-ansible-local puppet-server:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-provisioner-puppet-server file:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-provisioner-file puppet-masterless:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-provisioner-puppet-masterless converge:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-provisioner-converge shell:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-provisioner-shell windows-shell:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-provisioner-windows-shell ansible:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-provisioner-ansible chef-client:/bin/packer-PACKERSPACE-plugin-PACKERSPACE-packer-provisioner-chef-client]}
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Setting cache directory: /opt/packer_cache
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Loading builder: vmware-iso
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Plugin could not be found. Checking same directory as executable.
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Current exe path: /bin/packer
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Creating plugin client for path: /bin/packer
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Starting plugin: /bin/packer []string{"/bin/packer", "plugin", "packer-builder-vmware-iso"}
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Waiting for RPC address for: /bin/packer
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Detected home directory from env var: /root
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 [INFO] Packer version: 0.12.2
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Packer Target OS/Arch: linux amd64
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Built with Go Version: go1.7.4
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Detected home directory from env var: /root
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Attempting to open config file: /root/.packerconfig
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 [WARN] Config file doesn't exist: /root/.packerconfig
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Packer config: &{DisableCheckpoint:false DisableCheckpointSignature:false PluginMinPort:10000 PluginMaxPort:25000 Builders:map[] PostProcessors:map[] Provisioners:map[]}
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Setting cache directory: /opt/packer_cache
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 args: []string{"packer-builder-vmware-iso"}
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Plugin minimum port: 10000
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Plugin maximum port: 25000
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Detected home directory from env var: /root
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Plugin address: unix /tmp/packer-plugin313198337
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Waiting for connection...
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Serving a plugin connection...
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Loading provisioner: shell
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Plugin could not be found. Checking same directory as executable.
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Current exe path: /bin/packer
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Creating plugin client for path: /bin/packer
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Starting plugin: /bin/packer []string{"/bin/packer", "plugin", "packer-provisioner-shell"}
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Waiting for RPC address for: /bin/packer
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 [INFO] Packer version: 0.12.2
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Packer Target OS/Arch: linux amd64
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Built with Go Version: go1.7.4
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Detected home directory from env var: /root
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Attempting to open config file: /root/.packerconfig
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 [WARN] Config file doesn't exist: /root/.packerconfig
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Packer config: &{DisableCheckpoint:false DisableCheckpointSignature:false PluginMinPort:10000 PluginMaxPort:25000 Builders:map[] PostProcessors:map[] Provisioners:map[]}
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Setting cache directory: /opt/packer_cache
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Detected home directory from env var: /root
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 args: []string{"packer-provisioner-shell"}
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Plugin minimum port: 10000
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Plugin maximum port: 25000
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Plugin address: unix /tmp/packer-plugin616462938
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Waiting for connection...
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Serving a plugin connection...
2017/02/02 02:06:40 ui: [1;32mvmware-iso output will be in this color.[0m
2017/02/02 02:06:40 ui: 
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Build debug mode: false
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Force build: false
2017/02/02 02:06:40 On error: 
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Preparing build: vmware-iso
[1;32mvmware-iso output will be in this color.[0m

2017/02/02 02:06:40 Waiting on builds to complete...
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Starting build run: vmware-iso
2017/02/02 02:06:40 Running builder: vmware-iso
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 reconnecting to TCP connection for SSH
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 handshaking with SSH
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Keyboard interactive challenge:
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 -- User:
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 -- Instructions:
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 -- Question 1: Password:
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Keyboard interactive challenge:
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 -- User:
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 -- Instructions:
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 handshake complete!
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 [INFO] no local agent socket, will not connect agent
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 opening new ssh session
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 starting remote command: esxcli --formatter csv system version get
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 Connected to VMware ESXi 6.0.0 Releasebuild-4192238
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 opening new ssh session
2017/02/02 02:06:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:40 starting remote command: esxcli --formatter csv system settings advanced list -o /Net/GuestIPHack
2017/02/02 02:06:41 ui: [1;32m==> vmware-iso: Downloading or copying ISO[0m
[1;32m==> vmware-iso: Downloading or copying ISO[0m
[0;32m    vmware-iso: Downloading or copying: file:///opt/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso[0m
2017/02/02 02:06:41 ui: [0;32m    vmware-iso: Downloading or copying: file:///opt/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso[0m
2017/02/02 02:06:41 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:41 Acquiring lock to download: file:///opt/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso
2017/02/02 02:06:41 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:41 Parsed URL: &url.URL{Scheme:"file", Opaque:"", User:(*url.Userinfo)(nil), Host:"", Path:"/opt/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso", RawPath:"", ForceQuery:false, RawQuery:"", Fragment:""}
2017/02/02 02:06:41 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:41 [DEBUG] Using local file: /opt/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso
2017/02/02 02:06:41 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:41 Verifying checksum of /opt/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 opening new ssh session
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 starting remote command: test -e /vmfs/volumes/Local_SSD/output-vmware-iso
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 Remote command exited with '1': test -e /vmfs/volumes/Local_SSD/output-vmware-iso
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 opening new ssh session
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 starting remote command: mkdir -p /vmfs/volumes/Local_SSD/output-vmware-iso
2017/02/02 02:06:48 ui: [1;32m==> vmware-iso: Creating floppy disk...[0m
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 Floppy path: /tmp/packer258977900
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 Initializing block device backed by temporary file
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 Formatting the block device with a FAT filesystem...
[1;32m==> vmware-iso: Creating floppy disk...[0m
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 Initializing FAT filesystem on block device
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 Reading the root directory from the filesystem
2017/02/02 02:06:48 ui: [0;32m    vmware-iso: Copying files flatly from floppy_files[0m
[0;32m    vmware-iso: Copying files flatly from floppy_files[0m
2017/02/02 02:06:48 ui: [0;32m    vmware-iso: Copying file: /opt/files/centos-kickstart.cfg[0m
[0;32m    vmware-iso: Copying file: /opt/files/centos-kickstart.cfg[0m
2017/02/02 02:06:48 ui: [0;32m    vmware-iso: Done copying files from floppy_files[0m
2017/02/02 02:06:48 ui: [0;32m    vmware-iso: Collecting paths from floppy_dirs[0m
2017/02/02 02:06:48 ui: [0;32m    vmware-iso: Resulting paths from floppy_dirs : [][0m
[0;32m    vmware-iso: Done copying files from floppy_files[0m
2017/02/02 02:06:48 ui: [0;32m    vmware-iso: Done copying paths from floppy_dirs[0m
[0;32m    vmware-iso: Collecting paths from floppy_dirs[0m
2017/02/02 02:06:48 ui: [1;32m==> vmware-iso: Uploading Floppy to remote machine...[0m
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 Remote uploading: /tmp/packer258977900
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 opening new ssh session
[0;32m    vmware-iso: Resulting paths from floppy_dirs : [][0m
[0;32m    vmware-iso: Done copying paths from floppy_dirs[0m
[1;32m==> vmware-iso: Uploading Floppy to remote machine...[0m
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 starting remote command: mkdir -p /vmfs/volumes/Local_SSD/packer_cache
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 Verifying checksum of /vmfs/volumes/Local_SSD/packer_cache/packer258977900
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 opening new ssh session
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 starting remote command: sha256sum -c
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 Remote command exited with '1': sha256sum -c
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 opening new ssh session
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 Starting remote scp process:  scp -vt /vmfs/volumes/Local_SSD/packer_cache
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 Started SCP session, beginning transfers...
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 Copying input data into temporary file so we can read the length
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 [DEBUG] scp: Uploading packer258977900: perms=C0644 size=1474560
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 SCP session complete, closing stdin pipe.
2017/02/02 02:06:48 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:48 Waiting for SSH session to complete.
2017/02/02 02:06:49 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:49 scp stderr (length 36): Sink: C0644 1474560 packer258977900
[1;32m==> vmware-iso: Uploading ISO to remote machine...[0m
2017/02/02 02:06:49 ui: [1;32m==> vmware-iso: Uploading ISO to remote machine...[0m
2017/02/02 02:06:49 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:49 Remote uploading: /opt/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso
2017/02/02 02:06:49 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:49 opening new ssh session
2017/02/02 02:06:49 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:49 starting remote command: mkdir -p /vmfs/volumes/Local_SSD/packer_cache
2017/02/02 02:06:49 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:49 Verifying checksum of /vmfs/volumes/Local_SSD/packer_cache/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso
2017/02/02 02:06:49 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:49 opening new ssh session
2017/02/02 02:06:49 packer: 2017/02/02 02:06:49 starting remote command: sha256sum -c
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 Initial checksum matched, no upload needed.
2017/02/02 02:07:00 ui: [1;32m==> vmware-iso: Creating virtual machine disk[0m
[1;32m==> vmware-iso: Creating virtual machine disk[0m
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 opening new ssh session
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 starting remote command: vmkfstools -c 16384M -d zeroedthick -a lsilogic /vmfs/volumes/Local_SSD/output-vmware-iso/disk.vmdk
2017/02/02 02:07:00 ui: [1;32m==> vmware-iso: Building and writing VMX file[0m
[1;32m==> vmware-iso: Building and writing VMX file[0m
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 Writing VMX to: /tmp/packer-vmx282708606/packer-vmware-iso.vmx
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 Setting VMX: 'ethernet0.uptCompatibility' = 'TRUE'
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 Setting VMX: 'ethernet0.networkName' = 'VM Network'
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 Setting VMX: 'ethernet0.present' = 'TRUE'
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 Setting VMX: 'ethernet0.startConnected' = 'TRUE'
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 Setting VMX: 'ethernet0.virtualDev' = 'e1000'
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 Setting VMX: 'ethernet0.addressType' = 'generated'
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 Setting VMX: 'ethernet0.wakeOnPcktRcv' = 'FALSE'
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 Floppy path present, setting in VMX
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 Writing VMX to: /tmp/packer-vmx282708606/packer-vmware-iso.vmx
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 Suppressing messages in VMX
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 Looking for available port between 5900 and 6000
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 opening new ssh session
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 starting remote command: esxcli --formatter csv network ip connection list
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 ESXi listening on address :::5989, port 5989 unavailable for VNC
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 ESXi listening on address ::1:8889, port 8889 unavailable for VNC
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 ESXi listening on address fe80:2::6600:6aff:fe88:adfe:427, port 427 unavailable for VNC
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 ESXi listening on address 192.168.110.124:427, port 427 unavailable for VNC
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 ESXi listening on address 0.0.0.0:443, port 443 unavailable for VNC
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 ESXi listening on address :::443, port 443 unavailable for VNC
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 ESXi listening on address 0.0.0.0:80, port 80 unavailable for VNC
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 ESXi listening on address :::80, port 80 unavailable for VNC
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 ESXi listening on address :::22, port 22 unavailable for VNC
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 ESXi listening on address 0.0.0.0:22, port 22 unavailable for VNC
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 ESXi listening on address :::902, port 902 unavailable for VNC
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 ESXi listening on address 0.0.0.0:902, port 902 unavailable for VNC
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 ESXi listening on address :::8000, port 8000 unavailable for VNC
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 ESXi listening on address :::8300, port 8300 unavailable for VNC
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 ESXi listening on address :::8100, port 8100 unavailable for VNC
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 ESXi listening on address ::1:2233, port 2233 unavailable for VNC
2017/02/02 02:07:00 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:00 Trying address: 192.168.110.124:5900...
2017/02/02 02:07:01 packer: 2017/02/02 02:07:01 Timeout connecting to: 192.168.110.124:5900 (check firewall rules)
```

...etc.

```
2017/02/02 02:08:29 packer: 2017/02/02 02:08:29 Trying address: 192.168.110.124:5988...
2017/02/02 02:08:30 packer: 2017/02/02 02:08:30 Timeout connecting to: 192.168.110.124:5988 (check firewall rules)
2017/02/02 02:08:30 packer: 2017/02/02 02:08:30 Port 5989 in use
2017/02/02 02:08:30 packer: 2017/02/02 02:08:30 Trying address: 192.168.110.124:5990...
2017/02/02 02:08:31 packer: 2017/02/02 02:08:31 Timeout connecting to: 192.168.110.124:5990 (check firewall rules)
```

...etc.

```
2017/02/02 02:08:39 packer: 2017/02/02 02:08:39 Trying address: 192.168.110.124:5999...
2017/02/02 02:08:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:08:40 Timeout connecting to: 192.168.110.124:5999 (check firewall rules)
2017/02/02 02:08:40 packer: 2017/02/02 02:08:40 Trying address: 192.168.110.124:6000...
[1;31m==> vmware-iso: Unable to find available VNC port between 5900 and 6000[0m
2017/02/02 02:08:41 packer: 2017/02/02 02:08:41 Timeout connecting to: 192.168.110.124:6000 (check firewall rules)
2017/02/02 02:08:41 ui error: [1;31m==> vmware-iso: Unable to find available VNC port between 5900 and 6000[0m
2017/02/02 02:08:41 packer: 2017/02/02 02:08:41 Deleting floppy disk: /tmp/packer258977900
2017/02/02 02:08:41 packer: 2017/02/02 02:08:41 opening new ssh session
2017/02/02 02:08:41 packer: 2017/02/02 02:08:41 starting remote command: test -e /vmfs/volumes/Local_SSD/output-vmware-iso
2017/02/02 02:08:41 ui: [1;32m==> vmware-iso: Deleting output directory...[0m
[1;32m==> vmware-iso: Deleting output directory...[0m
2017/02/02 02:08:41 packer: 2017/02/02 02:08:41 opening new ssh session
2017/02/02 02:08:41 packer: 2017/02/02 02:08:41 starting remote command: rm -rf /vmfs/volumes/Local_SSD/output-vmware-iso
2017/02/02 02:08:41 ui error: [1;31mBuild 'vmware-iso' errored: Unable to find available VNC port between 5900 and 6000[0m
2017/02/02 02:08:41 Builds completed. Waiting on interrupt barrier...
2017/02/02 02:08:41 machine readable: error-count []string{"1"}
2017/02/02 02:08:41 ui error: 
==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
2017/02/02 02:08:41 machine readable: vmware-iso,error []string{"Unable to find available VNC port between 5900 and 6000"}
2017/02/02 02:08:41 ui error: --> vmware-iso: Unable to find available VNC port between 5900 and 6000
2017/02/02 02:08:41 ui: 
==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
2017/02/02 02:08:41 waiting for all plugin processes to complete...
[1;31mBuild 'vmware-iso' errored: Unable to find available VNC port between 5900 and 6000[0m

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> vmware-iso: Unable to find available VNC port between 5900 and 6000

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
2017/02/02 02:08:41 /bin/packer: plugin process exited
2017/02/02 02:08:41 /bin/packer: plugin process exited
```

Related issues:

- https://github.com/mitchellh/packer/issues/1372
- https://github.com/mitchellh/packer/issues/1480
- https://github.com/mitchellh/packer/issues/2676

Comment: You might be hitting a problem that your ESXi doesn't respond quickly enough on the connection probing. It would be interesting if you could try with a build from master where we recently merged a fix in https://github.com/mitchellh/packer/pull/4480 for this.

Comment: Just used the `hashicorp/packer:full` docker image to run the build, and it doesn't look like the fix has been included. The binary on that reports as 0.12.3. Isn't that image on an automatic build trigger?

Comment: I think thats just the latest build, try `packer version`.

Comment: I can see from https://hub.docker.com/r/hashicorp/packer/tags/ that the image hasn't been updated since before the fix got merged. I've just updated the code in the `:full` image and will try building and running from that.

Comment: Yup, works like a charm on the first port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest source has fixed the problem solved in the pull-request that @rickard-von-essen mentioned.

---

For future edification, to build the latest packer from source:

1. Go to your project directory, and run the following command: `docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/sh -v $(pwd):/opt/ -w /opt/ hashicorp/packer:full` Note: You can just replace `$(pwd)` with whatever your local project directory is.
2. Once the image downloads and you're put into the shell, change directory to `/go/src/github.com/mitchellh/packer` and run the following series of commands:

   1. `git pull`
   2. `apk add make`
   3. `make deps generate dev`
3. Change back to `/opt/`, and now you can run your packer commands.

You can easily automate this procedure in another Dockerfile or packer build to get a bleeding-edge docker image.